# Download a YouTube video that exists on GooglePlay

Tags: python, http, video, curl, youtube

How would I download the following video file? https://play.google.com/video/avi/player?aid=yt:movie:yM96M_vv8rM&autoplay=1&authuser=0&player=gpm

Normally, I can download it from YouTube -- but in the above case this video is 'restricted' and cannot be downloaded directly from YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyTVY3BAbYg. How would I download it directly from the first link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download it using the FireFox Add-On "FLASH AND VIDEO DOWNLOAD"

[FLASH AND VIDEO DOWNLOAD](http://www.fnvfox.com/)

It is broken into 4 segments of 1.98 MB each.
  I watched the first segment and did not attempt to concatenate the four files into one.  They must be reassembled, the 2nd-4th segment cannot be viewed by themselves.